# Adding a structured tagged value through c# add-in in enterprise architect

Tags: c#, add-in, enterprise-architect

I have a Add-in in C#, and I am running Enterprise Architect through it. And now I have an access to "system output window" in Enterprise Architect, which can be displayed/docked over EA's GUI. And now I need to get access to "Properties window" by which I can create a new(my own custom tab)like Property dialogue window inside that window.

The Subject is to have a "structured Tagged Values" created from Add-in. And those tagged values have to come inside a "CUSTOMIZED NEW TAB" in the Properties window of an element. For that we need to get the control over the "properties window" in Enterprise Architect from Add-in.

Plz suggest us the way on how to create a "NEW TAB" inside a properties window of an element.

Comment: Your comment to my answer suggests that you are after something else. Please edit your question to make that clear. I voted for closing else.

Comment: I have edited the above question, please check.

Comment: I have retracted my vote, but I also have no answer. Maybe Geert will have one.

Comment: @Kilian Sure. Thank u.

Comment: Are you asking to modify the default properties window of EA?

Comment: Seems like he is asking how to add a tab in which the tagvalues are displayed, much like how they are displayed when they come from a profile, I don't know if you can do this without a profile

Answer (score 0):

Enterprise Architect does not (yet) have any possibility to extend any existing popup windows with extra tabs. (This is also not possible using MDG technologies. Some MDG technologies extend EA, but these are incorporated in the application and not loaded through a separate XML file.)

The API does offer you an option to create **new** controls in the form of;

- Tabs: `Repository.AddTab`
- Addin Windows (dockable/floating): `Repository.AddWindow`

You could show your desired content of an API element in such a control. Or you could, using WPF or Windows Forms, create and show a custom popup window. You could even make that popup window modal as to block any further access (like the properties window does).